# sum of integer in a string

Tags: java, string, sum

Given a string parse the integers and sum it up

So heres the code ive written so far in java

```
public static int find(String s) {
    int sum = 0;
    String temp = "";

    //loop through string
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);

        //chracter is a digit then we store the digit in a Temporary String
        //loop through the next character, if its a digit again then we add the digit to temp
        //if the next character is not a digit then we sum up the digits and reset temp back to zero to recalculate new ints
        if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
            temp = temp + c;
        } else {
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(temp);
            temp = "0";
        }
    }

    return sum + Integer.parseInt(temp);
}

String s = "12he123sd-2";

//should give me 133
//but the negative sign isn't being parsed
```

I've tried adding a new **else if** block, but it doesnt seem to work

```
else if (c == '-')  temp = temp + c;
```

or

```
else if (c == '-' && Character.isDigit(c+1)) 
   temp = temp + c;
```

Comment: Why don't you ignore `-` when doing your calculations if it exists (skip to index 1) and then at the end multiple by `-1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it without regular expressions, you can modify your approach as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                  //       123 + 32 - 23 - 1 - 0 + 211 = 342
        int sum = find("sum123the32num-23-1be-0rs211found-done");
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public static int find(String s) {
        int sum = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int sign = 1;
        // loop through string
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                // was previous character a negative sign
                if (i > 0 &&  s.charAt(i-1) == '-') {
                    sign = -1;
                }
                // subtract '0' to convert char to binary
                // then convert entire number to binary 
                temp = temp * 10 + c - '0';
            } else {
                // non digit encountered so add to sump
                sum = sum + (sign * temp);
                System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
                temp = 0;
                sign = 1;
            } 
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Several things need explaining beyond program comments.

1. A character `1` in ASCII so it needs to be converted to an int value of 1 to be useful.  This can be done by subtracting `0` from it and from all digits other digits as encountered.
2. To convert a number of sequential digits to a complete number do the following.  Use "927" as an example

   - `set temp = 0;`
   - `temp = temp * 10 + c - '0'; // first time thru temp = 9`
   - `temp = temp * 10 + c - '0'; // now temp = 92`
   - `temp = temp * 10 + c - '0'; // now temp = 927`

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to solve it by using regex. Is this what you want?

```
public static int find(String s) {
    int sum = 0;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(-?\\d+)").matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the necessary `(...)` capture group and use [`m.group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group--) instead.

Comment: In Java 9+, you can do it in one statement using streams: `return Pattern.compile("-?\\d+").matcher(s).results().mapToInt(r -> Integer.parseInt(r.group())).sum();`